# How to Center the Content inside Mat-Card Component - Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I would like to align the image and button content to the center of the mat-card.

Have attempted to utilize the following CSS styles:
justify-content: center
margin-left: auto , margin-right: auto
margin-left: 50% , margin-right: 50%
content-align: center
etc.

I attempted all of the solutions provided by Andrew Lobban at this point. I am immensely grateful for his patience in trying to find a solution with me.

The Card Component is as follows:

HTML

```
<div>
<mat-grid-list cols="6" rowHeight="250px">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of card" [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">
      <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
        <mat-card-header>
        </mat-card-header>
        <div>
        <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
           <img src={{card.IMGPath}}>
          <a mat-raised-button color="primary" href={{card.ButtonLink}}>{{card.ButtonLabel}}</a>
        </mat-card-content>
      </div>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid-container {
    margin: 20px;
  }

  .dashboard-card {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    max-width: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
  }

.dashboard-card-content {
    justify-content: center
  }
```

Typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-property-management',
  templateUrl: './property-management.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./property-management.component.css']
})
export class PropertyManagementComponent {

  card = [{ 
    title: 'Capital Control', cols: 1, rows: 1, 
    IMGPath: 'redacted' ,
    ButtonLabel:'Capital Control',
    ButtonLink:'redacted'
  },
  { 
    title: 'New Entity', cols: 1, rows: 1, 
    IMGPath: 'redacted' ,
    ButtonLabel:'New Entity',
    ButtonLink:'redacted'
  },
  ];

}
```

The cards are utilized here:
HTML

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <h3 class="mat-h3">Property Management</h3>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <app-property-management></app-property-management>
  <h3 class="mat-h3">Information Technology</h3>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <app-information-technology></app-information-technology>
</div>
```

With this code, they render as follows: [Current Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2cRE.png)

Thank you to everyone for their time and patience.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems you are looking for the CSS style `justify-content: center`. This will center your content in the Mat-Card-Content.

I am sure there are many ways to do this, but I use this or I use @angular/flex-layout along with `fxLayout="row"` (or column) `fxLayoutAlign="center"` attributes.

[image]

Comment: The CSS style justify-content: center, has had no effect on the result. I will try the method with Flex Layout

Comment: I would say simplify you css for the class .dashboard-card-content by commenting out any other styles. Also can you provide a screen shot of what the render looks like?

Comment: No problem at all, thank you for your help! I really appreciate it. I added a screenshot to the original post!

Comment: If you remove/disable the class `.dashboard-card` do you get the content justification you want?

Comment: Renders on the screen exactly the same way as the screenshot with justify-content: center.

I can confirm that it is compiling after the changes are saved. So this behavior seems very odd to me.

Comment: Try wrapping the card content in `<div>` and applying the `justify-content` on it. Also try using the Chrome Dev Tools to set the CSS style on the `<mat-card-content>` if the former doesn't work.

Comment: Andrew, thank you again for your time and patience. unfortunately it does not work in practice, or in the developer tools. I have updated my original post to reflect the changes. If you have any other ideas, please let me know. I may need to investigate on how to implement the flex-layout module.

Comment: Here is a replication of your work on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-content-center

Comment: I ended rewriting the card component : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-dashboard-project

I utilized the mat-card-image and css margins to get the layout that i desired.

Comment: @PCorruthers, I am glad I was able to help!